# How to get and put columns name of Excel using Java?

Tags: java, excel, jexcelapi

How to get column name of Excel sheets using Java? I am using jexcel package for reading from and writing into excel sheet. And also how to change a column name of an Excel sheet?

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Java and Excel are you talking about?

For all versions of Excel till Excel 2003 you can use http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/.

For 2007, you can use http://poi.apache.org/index.html

I do not know of any Java APIs for Excel 2010. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

POI supports Excel 2010 as well. Using the XSSF library is suggested as the xlsx files tend to be slower to parse:

http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/index.html